# Are There Any Monophthong [o] Words in English?

Tags: english, phonology, phonetics, vowels

Whenever I look up a transcription for a word containing [o], it's either an [oɪ] diphthong or an [oʊ] diphthong. Is it not possible to pronounce [o] without gliding through [ʊ] too? Is it possible, but English simply doesn't do it? Or, do monophthong [o] words actually exist in English, and I simply haven't been able to find them?
EDIT: This question regards any dialect of English.

Comment: Which dialect of English? Each one has different vowels.

Comment: @curiousdannii For both British and American.

Comment: @abcjme you should edit the question to reflect that

Comment: [This](http://www.lel.ed.ac.uk/research/gsound/Eng/Database/Phonetics/Englishes/Home/HomeMainFrameHolder.htm) is an incredibly useful and informative resource whenever you want to find how English accents around the world realize words. (Take it with a grain of salt, though, because the transcriptions are very narrow, they rely on one speaker per accent, and the words are said in careful speech, not casual.)

Comment: @Nardog Thanks! Ya, that resource is amazing! I'll save that link! It clearly shows that Scottish and Indian dialects have a plain [o] in words.

Comment: If you like that, check out the [George Mason Accent Archive](http://accent.gmu.edu/). Includes native dialects and foreign dialects of English, transcribed in IPA and identified as to location and language background.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Standard American English and Standard British English, no. /o/ is always realized as a diphthong, primarily [oʊ], or [o] may appear in other diphthongs, e.g. [oɪ] although this is usually closer to [ɔɪ]. In some dialects of English, notably Indian English and I believe some types of Caribbean English too, /o/ can be realized as a monophthongal [o].

Comment: In what accent is /o/ pronounced as [oɪ]? (Not questioning your answer, just trying to figure out what OP meant.)

Comment: @Nardog that was a mistake, see my edit.

Comment: Monophthongal /o/ is a notable feature of Scottish English and [Geordie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geordie). Also found in [Welsh English](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Welsh_English) and [North-Central American English](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/North-Central_American_English).

Comment: @Nardog thank you for that information. However, the page for NCAE mentions that the dialect does have a [oʊ] in some cases

Comment: So does WE. Notice the words "also found". ;)

Comment: @Nardog I originally found examples online of [oɪ] words. However, when checking British and American transcriptions, they actually show up as [ɔɪ] (ex. "boy").

Comment: @abcjme That difference is just convention. Phonemic notations (in slashes) and phonetic transcriptions (in brackets) are two entirely different beasts. You should look up the differences. I recommend [this article](https://www.phon.ucl.ac.uk/home/wells/transcription-ELL.pdf) as a starter.

Comment: Come to think of it, /ɔː/ is nowadays frequently pronounced with a quality closer to [o] than [ɔ] in RP (or whatever you want to call the prestigious Southern British accent), so it is kind of found in Standard British English. ([source](https://www.cambridge.org/core/services/aop-cambridge-core/content/view/D4AFF0A7118E7081ACF7C7586FF87590/S0025100304001768a.pdf/british_english_received_pronunciation.pdf#page=4))

Comment: In American English lects, there is normally a fairly pure [o] before [ɹ], where /o/ and /ɔ/ neutralize (i.e, there is no contrast in these lects between /or/ and /ɔr/). This neutralization is similar to that among /e/, /ɛ/, and /æ/ before /r/, as in _Mary, merry, marry_, which are only distinguished in N. America in New England; the rest of us pronounce them identically.

Comment: @jlawler Where there is no contrast between /or/ and /ɔr/, the realization of either seems to be [ɔr].

Comment: @Nardog I read that article. It seems that /x/ is used for simple and broad notation and [x] is used for comparative and narrow transcription, is that correct?

There are also at least 8 popular transciption standards. Problematically, the transcription sites that I've seen don't note which standard they use. Is that typical? Is a user of a site supposed to just deduce which standard it's using?

Comment: @ubadub Quite the contrary. It is in the dialects which contrast NORTH and FORCE that NORTH sounds like [ɔɹ]. In others, both NORTH and FORCE is usually midway between [o] and [ɔ], if not closer to [o].

Comment: @abcjme If you're talking about dictionaries, they all have pronunciation keys in the front matter. Online, you may have to look a bit harder: e.g. [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/help/phonetics.html), [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/help), [American Heritage](https://www.ahdictionary.com/application/resources/misc/pronkey.pdf). If you're talking about sites like the George Mason Accent Archive, they are impressionistic transcriptions so the key is the [IPA chart](https://linguistics.ucla.edu/people/keating/IPA/IPA_unitipa_2018_full.pdf).

Comment: @abcjme In that paper, [x] (voiceless velar fricative) is only used in the allophonic (≈ narrow ≈ impressionistic) transcription and denotes an allophone of /k/ where the tongue does not completely stop the airflow (/meɪkɪŋ/ → [meɪxɪŋ]). In some English dialects (usually those in Celtic countries), the same sound exists as a *phoneme* (i.e. /x/, found in *loch* etc.), but that's a completely different thing from the [x] in that RP transcription.

Comment: @Nardog in what dialects does English /k/ realize as [x]? I've literally never heard such a thing

Comment: @ubadub That's just because the allophonic transcription of the paper (Roach 2004) adopts a very narrow transcription. Intervocalic stops are frequently realized without complete occlusion if we're getting really specific.

Comment: @Nardog I meant "x" as a variable. I now realize how confusing that was of me. I was just asking about [] and // in general.

Comment: @abcjme I see. Basically, any letter or letter combination in a transcription enclosed in slashes (e.g. /tʃɛkðəlɛnzwɛl/) is a phoneme—a set of similar sounds distinctive in a language. A transcription in brackets (or nothing, usually in bold) can include any amount/kinds of information depending on one's intention: It can be the same as the phonemic ([tʃɛkðəlɛnzwɛl]), very detailed ([tʃe̞ʔ͡kð̞əlɛ̃nzwæ̠ɫ]), or partially detailed ([tʃɛkðəlɛnzwɛɫ]). See [IPA Handbook pp. 29–30](https://books.google.com/books?id=33BSkFV_8PEC&pg=PA29).

Comment: @abcjme For "transcription standards", see [this answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/439935/194620) by sumelic. I know, it's pretty messy.

Comment: @Nardog Understood, thanks so much!

Comment: @nardog That post is terrible! (Sumelic's posts are normally ok. That one's an anomally)

Answer (score 3):

Words like *load, go, row* are sometimes treated as having the phonological vowel /o/. That is a phonemic analysis of the where vowels are tense or lax, so we have the opposition i/ɪ, e/ɛ, u/ʊ, o/ɔ. Phonetically, it is usually recognized that the mid vowels are diphthongs, written as [ei], [ɛɪ] or [ɛi] among others. I think the phonetic facts support [ɛɪ, ɔʊ] over the competitors. The quality [ɔ] also occurs before [ɹ] as in "core". There are American and British dialects (spoken in the north, in both cases) where "goat" is [go:t]. I can't say that there isn't a dialect where short *o* in *got, rot, sop* is phonetic [o], but I haven't heard of one. I would say that short monophthongal [o] is non-existent in English.

Comment: I think OP means the phonetic realization, not the letter nor the phoneme

Comment: @ubadub At the second glance, now it seems the question is whether a monophthongal [o] is found in English, not the phoneme /o/. Otherwise it doesn't make sense to mention "oɪ".

Comment: Yes, that seems clear.

Comment: And yet, people frequently confuse the two kinds of analysis, so as a public service it is best to clarify the difference, when a question leaves open the intended analysis.

Answer (score 2):

According to the table in [Wiktionary Appendix:English pronunciation](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Appendix:English_pronunciation#Vowels) words like *not* are pronounced using ɒ,ɔ or ɒ and words like *force* are pronounced using ɔː, oː  oɹ, ɔɹ similar to words like *horse* (depending on the dialect of English).

So if you require `o` and do not allow `ɔ` there is still the possibility of the long `oː` or the `o` before an `ɹ`.

Comment: @ Vladimir F Ah, but even then, as a monophthong, it's strange that it must be long, or followed by an approximant. Are there are no circumstances in which a regular-length monophthong "o" can be followed by a consonant?

Comment: @abcjme This is because of [open syllable lengthening in Middle English](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Middle_English_phonology#Open-syllable_lengthening), around the 13th century

Comment: @abcjme The tendency for the shorter vowel to be lax is still current across British & American English (compare the vowels of FLEECE and KIT, PUT and BOOT), but also Standard German and Dutch.